# Adding a new DF column that changes based on other columns signs using np.sign()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I was wondering if there was a way to fill a column using np.sign where the column looks at two other columns and returns the same sign if both columns are equal to each other. Otherwise it stays the **same as the previous row** until both columns are the same.

More specific case using my pd.dataframe:

```
       col_1 col_2 col_3 col_a col_b final_col  # final_col swiches
row_1   10     5    5     +1    +1     +1       # start +1 except if a = -1
row_2   10     15   5     -1    +1     +1       # only one flips, stays +1
row_3   10     15   15    -1    -1     -1       # both flip to same sign, changes to -1
row_4   20     15   15    +1    +1     +1       # both flip to same sign, changes to +1
row_5   20     25   25    -1    -1     -1       # both flip to same sign, changes to -1
row_6   20     15   25    +1    -1     -1       # only one flips, stays -1
row_7   20     25   15    -1    +1     -1       # both flip to different sign, stays -1
```

row_1, row_2, row_3 have various positive integers with mostly up trend but may go down at times (never negative).

Here is what I had to get started but I am not sure how to go forward:

```
df["col_a"] = np.sign(df.col_1.sub(df.col_3)) 
df["col_b"] = np.sign(df.col_1.sub(df.col_2))
df["final_col"] = np.sign(df.col_a.eq(df.col_b)) # gave an UFuncTypeError error
df
```

As you can see in the code: 
np.sign(<>.sub(<>)) the following is true:

```
col_a = +1 if col_1 > col_3
col_a = -1 if col_1 < col_3
col_b = +1 if col_1 > col_2
col_b = -1 if col_1 < col_2
```

Any suggestions I can try will be very helpful, it does not have to use np.sign. Thank you!

Comment: It gives you an error because you are passing a Boolean returned by df7.col_a.eq(df7.col_b) to np.sign - booleans don't have signs!

Comment: Yup, that is correct. Using eq would test if boolean. I could easily fix the main problem if I could use if statements but I'm not sure how to go at it. Maybe using .apply()? I can write the function but I'm not sure how to incorporate it.

Comment: "and return the same sign": the same sign as what?  the sign of the two columns (when they are equal) or the sign in the previous row?

Comment: Of the previous row

Comment: can you comment on the answer I provided? Is it the correct understanding?

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the following interpretation of the question:

- `col_a` and `col_b` (hereafter called `a` and `b`) are signs in `{-1, 1}`;
- from one row to the next, zero or more of `a`, `b` can "flip" (change sign);
- for each row, there is a change bit that depends on `a` and `b` at that row, as well as the flip of `a` and `b`;
- `change` is `True` iff `a == b` and either `a` or `b` (or both) have flipped;
- the final result is a sign starting at +1 (no matter what the first row is) and that flips whenever `change` is `True`.

```py
a = df['col_a']
b = df['col_b']
change = ((a == b) & ((a.diff().fillna(0) != 0) | (b.diff().fillna(0) != 0)))
newdf = df.assign(final_col=(1 - 2 * change.astype(int)).cumprod())
```

On your example:

```py
>>> newdf
       col_1  col_2  col_3  col_a  col_b  final_col
row_1     10      5      5      1      1          1
row_2     10     15      5     -1      1          1
row_3     10     15     15     -1     -1         -1
row_4     20     15     15      1      1          1
row_5     20     25     25     -1     -1         -1
row_6     20     15     25      1     -1         -1
row_7     20     25     15     -1      1         -1
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, thank you <br>
- a and b are signs in {-1, 1} since pd.sign() will only output those two values regardless of the number. Only outputs sign, see below.<br>
- The sign depends on what is being subtracted. For example in df["col_a"] = np.sign(df.col_1.sub(df.col_3)), col_1 = 10,  col_3 = 5 then 10 - 5 = +5. Since it is positive and only the sign matters, col_a will have a value of +1. <br>
-  final is decided based on a and b. Final will remain the same as the previous row until both signs (either negative or positive) of a and b are the same. If same, that value overtakes final.

Comment: As you said, change is only true if a and b are the same signs. if they both flip to opposite signs but they remain different, final does not flip. <br> To make things more simple, final starts positive only if a starts positive as well

Comment: Right, I think that was my understanding. Is the answer consistent with what you need? If not, in which way does it differ, and can you include counter-examples in the question?  In other words, are there cases where this solution doesn't answer exactly your question?